# Efficiently find unique groups of subsets (e.g. unique shopping baskets)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame, with one column representing the index of shopping baskets. For each basket, I have another column identifying items within that basket. What is the most efficient way of finding the unique baskets in the dataset?

Here is an example utilising `dplyr`:

```
outer_num <- 10000
tmp_df <-
    data.frame(basket_index = rep(1:(8*outer_num), each = 2),
               items_purchased = rep(rep(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3), 2), outer_num))

items_purchased_df <-
    data.frame(items_purchased = 1:3, 
               item_name = c("shampoo", "soap", "conditioner"))

tmp_df_2 <-
    tmp_df %>%
    inner_join(items_purchased_df) %>%
    select(basket_index, items_purchased = item_name) 

head(tmp_df_2, 16)
#    basket_index items_purchased
# 1             1         shampoo
# 2             1         shampoo
# 3             2            soap
# 4             2            soap
# 5             3         shampoo
# 6             3         shampoo
# 7             4     conditioner
# 8             4     conditioner
# 9             5         shampoo
# 10            5         shampoo
# 11            6            soap
# 12            6            soap
# 13            7         shampoo
# 14            7         shampoo
# 15            8     conditioner
# 16            8     conditioner
```

In this example, we see that there are only three unique baskets with two items each. In general, baskets may not have identical number of items, may or may not have duplicate items, and in some cases the order of apperance of items in a basket matters.

The following function produces an acceptable output:

```
tmp_fn <- function(tmp_df) {
    tmp_df %>%
        group_by(basket_index) %>%
        mutate(collapsed_purchases = paste0(items_purchased, collapse = ',')) %>%
        group_by(collapsed_purchases) %>%
        filter(basket_index == min(basket_index)) %>%
        ungroup
}
```

So that

```
tmp_fn(tmp_df_2)
#   basket_index items_purchased collapsed_purchases    
#           <int> <fct>           <chr>                  
# 1            1 shampoo         shampoo,shampoo        
# 2            1 shampoo         shampoo,shampoo        
# 3            2 soap            soap,soap              
# 4            2 soap            soap,soap              
# 5            4 conditioner     conditioner,conditioner
# 6            4 conditioner     conditioner,conditioner
```

This is not terribly time efficient. Converting the item factors to integers (and assuming this is an instantaneous process!) speeds it up by nearly two orders of magnitude, but even on this small dataset still takes half a second:

```
tmp_df_3 <-
    tmp_df_2 %>%
    mutate(items_purchased_old = items_purchased,
           items_purchased = as.integer(factor(items_purchased)))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(tmp_fn(tmp_df_2), times = 10)
# Unit: seconds
#            expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# tmp_fn(tmp_df_2) 20.6301 20.93541 21.98261 22.24193 22.43473 23.77921    10

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(tmp_fn(tmp_df_3), times = 10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# tmp_fn(tmp_df_3) 348.3901 358.0814 507.7983 363.7639 387.2384 1566.903    10
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** My results are with `stringsAsFactors = F`. Without that, there was no significant performance gain compared to OP's `tmp_fn()` function.

---

As far as I know, `group_by + mutate` and `group_by + filter` are slow. Here's a way to avoid that -

```
# for outer_num <- 10000
system.time(
  res <- tmp_df_2 %>%
    group_by(basket_index) %>%
    summarize(collapsed_purchases = paste0(items_purchased, collapse = ',')) %>%
    filter(!duplicated(collapsed_purchases)) 
    # summarize drops one (in this case, the only) grouping level
    # so filter is on ungrouped data which is good; also duplicated() is fast enough
)

# user  system elapsed 
# 4.35    0.00    4.41 

res
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#   basket_index collapsed_purchases    
#          <int> <chr>                  
# 1            1 shampoo,shampoo        
# 2            2 soap,soap              
# 3            4 conditioner,conditioner

# get desired result
tmp_df_2 %>% 
  inner_join(res, by = "basket_index")

#   basket_index items_purchased     collapsed_purchases
# 1            1         shampoo         shampoo,shampoo
# 2            1         shampoo         shampoo,shampoo
# 3            2            soap               soap,soap
# 4            2            soap               soap,soap
# 5            4     conditioner conditioner,conditioner
# 6            4     conditioner conditioner,conditioner
```

**Note:**  Using `data.table` might provide even more speed.

Comment: I find that this works twice as fast when applied to `tmp_df3`, i.e. the data frame where the items are recoded to integers.

Comment: @Alex Good to know. I'll try and benchmark again tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

If you are satisfied with unique combination of items_purchased, `unique(list_data)` is TOO FAST.

```
tmp_df_2 %>%
  with(split(x = items_purchased, f = basket_index)) %>% 
  unique()

## output
# [[1]]
# [1] shampoo shampoo
# Levels: conditioner shampoo soap
#
# [[2]]
# [1] soap soap
# Levels: conditioner shampoo soap
#
# [[3]]
# [1] conditioner conditioner
# Levels: conditioner shampoo soap



f <- function() tmp_df_2 %>%
  with(split(x = items_purchased, f = basket_index)) %>% 
  unique()

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(tmp_fn(tmp_df_2), f(), times = 5)

# Unit: milliseconds  ## ! f() took 1 second or less !
# expr                    min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval cld
# tmp_fn(tmp_df_2) 22902.3614 24637.1447 24657.7256 24928.6063 25280.1145 25540.4009     5   b
# f()                657.4491   672.0378   674.6513   673.4228   676.9276   693.4191     5  a
```

[EDITED]
To handle real data, you need to sort data before `unique()`.

```
test_d <- data.frame(basket_index = c(rep(1, 2), rep(2, 2), rep(3, 3), rep(4, 3), rep(5, 3), rep(6, 2)),
                     items_purchased = letters[c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3,  2, 3, 1, 3, 4)])

tmp_fn(test_d) %>% distinct(collapsed_purchases)
#  collapsed_purchases  # Oops!
# 1 a,b                
# 2 b,a                
# 3 a,b,c              
# 4 b,c,a              
# 5 c,d    

test_d %>% 
  arrange(items_purchased) %>% 
  with(split(x = items_purchased, f = basket_index)) %>% 
  unique()

# [[1]]
# [1] a b
# Levels: a b c d
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] a b c
# Levels: a b c d
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] c d
# Levels: a b c d
```

Comment: nice, this is comparable to calling my original function on the items mapped to factors.

Comment: and applying it to `tmp_df3` leads to another magnitude of improvement.

Comment: Does this method handle order of items?

Comment: It should right? since `split` produces lists of vectors? I assume the vectors are ordered?

Comment: @Alex  I agree with Shree. In actual case, you need to sort before split (With `group_by %>% mutate(paste)` methods, this is the same). I'll edit my answer to use in actual scene.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with base R using `paste()` within an `aggregate()` and filter out the `duplicated`. In `aggregate` I prefer the `'data.frame'` over the `'formula'` method here in order to immediately get the `"collapsed_purchases"` column name (see `?aggregate`).

```
FUN <- function(dat) {
  res <- with(dat, aggregate(list(collapsed_purchases=items_purchased), 
                             by=list(basket_index=basket_index), paste, collapse=","))
  res <- res[!duplicated(res[2]), ]
  return(merge(tmp_df_2, res, all.y=T))
}
```

#### Results

```
> system.time(res2 <- FUN(tmp_df_2))
   user  system elapsed 
   1.73    0.01    1.76 
> res2
  basket_index items_purchased     collapsed_purchases
1            1         shampoo         shampoo,shampoo
2            1         shampoo         shampoo,shampoo
3            2            soap               soap,soap
4            2            soap               soap,soap
5            4     conditioner conditioner,conditioner
6            4     conditioner conditioner,conditioner
>
> system.time(res3 <- FUN(tmp_df_3))  # numerized version
   user  system elapsed 
   0.77    0.02    0.78 
> res3
  basket_index items_purchased collapsed_purchases
1            1         shampoo                 2,2
2            1         shampoo                 2,2
3            2            soap                 3,3
4            2            soap                 3,3
5            4     conditioner                 1,1
6            4     conditioner                 1,1
```